# Symfony 2: Clean up Doctrine metadata

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I faced a problem when I created entities from the existing database, then dropped all tables and entities, and created new entities.

1. I created database
2. Created entities and from existing database according to Symfony 2 docs
3. Then I removed all tables from the database
4. Removed all entities from `/Entity` directory
5. Removed `/doctrine` folder from `/config` directory
6. Created new entities, with metadata in annotations
7. Updated the database according to new entities

And when I tried to launch the application, I have got an exception

> Warning: class_parents() [function.class-parents]: Class WriterBeat\AdminBundle\Entity\Members does not exist and could not be loaded in D:\experiments\write\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService.php line 38

There was `Members` entity before step 4 when I removed it. And created new entity called `User`.

**UPD**

I found that problem is on security config file, and now I would like to ask you, how can disable security component until I will start implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with following command?

```
sudo php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```